# Entity Framework 6 automatically changes entity value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

- each `DIMPeriodDates` can connect to many `DIMPeriodComparatives` and
- each `DIMPeriodComparatives` can connect to many `DIMPeriodDates`

In other words, `DIMPeriod` can connect to themselves with order number.

This is the `DIMPeriod` class :

```
public class DIMPeriodDate
{
    public enum EnumDIMPeriodPresentStatus
    {
        Refresh,
        Operation
    }

    public enum EnumDIMPeriodType
    {
        Decisive,
        Predicted
    }

    public enum EnumDIMPeriodAuditStatus
    {
        Audited,
        NotAudited
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string? Desc { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    public List<DIMPeriodComparative> PeriodComparativeList { get; set; } = new();
    public List<DIMPeriodComparative> PeriodBaseComparativeList { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And this is the `PeriodComparative` class :

```
public class DIMPeriodComparative
{
    public int PeriodComparativeID { get; set; }
    public int PeriodBaseID { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; } = 1;

    public DIMPeriodDate PeriodComparative { get; set; }
    public DIMPeriodDate PeriodBase { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Fluent API config :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DIMPeriodComparative>()
            .HasKey(q => new { q.PeriodComparativeID, q.PeriodBaseID });

modelBuilder.Entity<DIMPeriodComparative>()
            .HasOne(q => q.PeriodComparative)
            .WithMany(q => q.PeriodComparativeList)
            .HasForeignKey(q=>q.PeriodComparativeID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

modelBuilder.Entity<DIMPeriodComparative>()
            .HasOne(q => q.PeriodBase)
            .WithMany(q => q.PeriodBaseComparativeList)
            .HasForeignKey(q=>q.PeriodBaseID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Now when I insert a new `DIMPeriodComparatives` entity to specific `DIMPeriodDates` like this :

[image]

After calling `SaveChanges`, the value automatically has changed :

[image]

`PeriodBase` and `PeriodComparative` have different Value with different id `11` and `13` ...

Comment: Sounds like it's a many-to-many but you're missing your junction table between DimPeriodComparatives and DimPeriodDates

Answer (score 0):

i change fulent api to this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DIMPeriodDate>()
            .HasMany(q => q.PeriodComparativeBase)
            .WithMany(q => q.PeriodComparative)
            .UsingEntity<DIMPeriodComparative>(right =>
            
                right.HasOne(q => q.PeriodComparative)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(q => q.PeriodComparativeID)
            , left =>
            left.HasOne(q=>q.PeriodBase)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(q=>q.PeriodBaseID)
            , joinent =>
            joinent.HasKey(q => new {q.PeriodComparativeID,q.PeriodBaseID})
            );
```

and issue is fixed ...